# Возможно ли выполнить изменения записи DML предложениями - INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE - через представление (view)?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, view

Возможно ли выполнить изменения записи DML выражениями - `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` через представление (*view*)?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/1652995/6571020

Answer (score 5):

Представления в БД могут быть изменяемыми (*updateable views*) при определённых условиях.

Выдержка из [Oracle SQL Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.html#GUID-61D2D2B4-DACC-4C7C-89EB-7E50D9594D30):

**Замечания для изменяемых представлений**

Изменяемое представление значит, что оно может быть использовано для изменения записей в его базовых таблицах. Можно создать представление, которое **в принципе** изменяемо (т.е. само по себе изменяемо), или также возможно создать для **любого** представления `INSTEAD OF` триггер, чтобы сделать его изменяемым.

Узнать, какие и каким образом колонки в принципе изменяемого (т.е изменяемого без триггера) представления могут быть изменены, можно посмотреть через представлние `USER_UPDATABLE_COLUMNS`.

Для того, чтобы представление могло быть изменено, все следующие условия должны выполнятся:

- Каждая колонка представления должна представлять колонку одной таблицы. Например, если колонка представляет вывод TABLE оператора, то это условие не выполняется.
- Представление не должно содержать одну из следующих конструкций:

  - `SET` оператор
  - `DISTINCT` оператор
  - Агрегатную или аналитическую функцию
  - `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, `MODEL`, `CONNECT BY`, или `START WITH` выражения
  - Выражение для коллекций в листе `SELECT`
  - Подзапрос в листе `SELECT`
  - Подзапрос с `WITH READ ONLY`
  - Соединения (*joins*), с некоторыми исключениями указаными в документе [Oracle Database Administrator's Guide](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf&id=ADMIN020)

Дополненительно, если в принципе изменяемое представление содержит псевдо колонки или выражения, то нельзя изменить записи таблицы с `UPDATE` предложением, которое обращается к этим псевдоколонкам или выражениям.

Если надо сделать изменяемым представление содержащее соединение таблиц, то все следующие условия должны быть соблюдены:

- DML предложение должно затрагивавть только одну таблицу соединения
- Для `INSERT` предложения, представление не должно быть создано с  `WITH CHECK OPTION`, и все колонки, в которые вставляются значения, должны происходить из таблицы с сохранёнными ключами. Таблица с сохранёнными ключами (*key-preserved table*), это базовая таблица, в которой каждое значение первичного или уникального ключа сохранит свою уникальность также в представлении после соединения.
- Для `UPDATE` предложения, представление не должно быть создано с  `WITH CHECK OPTION`, и все колонки, которые подлежат изменению, должны происходить из таблицы с сохранёнными ключами.
- Для `DELETE` предложения, если в результате соединения более чем одна таблица будет с сохранёнными ключами, то удаление будет из первой таблицы указанной в `FROM` выражении, независимо от того, было ли создано представление с `WITH CHECK OPTION` или без него.

<sub>Источник ответа [@DCookie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653192/6571020). При переводе сверенно с офф. документацией актуального релиза 19c</sub>

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Спасибо за правку! Там скорее всего был неудачный перевод. В оригинале и документации: _For a view to be inherently updatable_ , т.е. по своей природе изменяемо. Последнее показалось мне длинновато и я остановился на -- в принципе изменяемо.

Answer (score 3):

Если в созданном представлении существуют ограничения описанные в [ранее данном ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1038948/217579) и оно в принципе не изменяемо, то можно сделать его изменяемым через [INSTEAD OF триггер](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-9F06D45C-7C60-434E-A597-114A0C445671).

Простейший случай - изменения представления с `1:N` (*one-to-many*) связью:

```sql
create table items (id number primary key, item varchar2 (64));
create table parts (
    id number primary key, itemid number, part varchar2 (64),
    constraint fk_part foreign key (itemid) references items (id)
    );

create or replace view itemparts as
    select i.id itemid, i.item, p.part 
    from items i
    join parts p on p.itemid = i.id;
```

Попытки изменить таблицу `items`:

```sql
insert into itemparts (itemid, item) values (1, 'item 1');

update itemparts set
   item = item||'*'
where itemid = 1;
```

закончатся безуспешно потому, что первичный ключ `items.id` в преставлении не сохранил свою уникальность:

> ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
>   **Cause:**    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
>              map to a non-key-preserved table.
>   **Action:**   Modify the underlying base tables directly.

Сделаем представление изменяемым через триггер:

```sql
create or replace trigger trig_itemparts
instead of insert or update or delete on itemparts
declare dummypartid constant number := 1e20;
begin
    --dbms_output.put_line ('trig_mail_address_book: '||:new.pk_serial_no||'|'||:new.address_a||'|'||:new.address_b);
    if inserting then -- the same for updating, deleting 
        insert into items values (:new.itemid, :new.item);
        insert into parts values (dummypartid, :new.itemid, 'dummy part');
    elsif updating  then
        update items set item = :new.item
        where id = :new.itemid; 
    end if;
end;
/
```

Повторим попытки изменения (см. выше) и результат на лицо:

```sql
select * from itemparts
order by itemid;

    ITEMID ITEM       PART      
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 item 1*    dummy part
```