# Почему триггер в Oracle не реагирует на все строки, которые я вставляю в таблицу?

Tags: база-данных, oracle, plsql, триггер, insert

Есть такая таблица:

```
NAME    X   Y
------  --- ---
Sasha    30  75
Dasha    55 107
Oleg    123  41
Dima     77  50
Masha    27  57
Galina   91  30
```

Это таблица выстрелов. У меня есть люди, которые участвуют в соревновании по меткости в стрельбе. Колонка name описывает имя стрелка, колонка x показывает координату точки попадения пули x, а колонка y показывает координату точки попадения пули y. Подразумевается, что данные будут вноситься сразу по три строчки после того, как выстреливает каждая команда, состоящая из 3 человек. Вот как выглядит запрос вставки результатов выстрела:

```
insert all 
into shots
(name, x, y)
values
('Bill', 12, 61)
into shots
(name, x, y)
values
('Marat', 150, 85)
into shots
(name, x, y)
values
('Ivan', 18, 13)
select * from dual;
```

И тут есть одно ограничение. Нельзя записывать в таблицу результат, в котором x > 120. Поэтому был написан триггер, который отменяет вставку строки, у которой x > 120. Вот его код:

```
create or replace trigger delet_shot
    before INSERT on shots
for each row
begin
    if (:new.x > 120) then
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Стрелок не попал в мишень');
    end if;
end;
```

В чём суть вопроса. Когда я выполняю вставку в таблицу, продемонстрированную выше, у меня из-за того, что в запросе присутствует строка, которая не может быть вставлена из-за триггера, не вставляются две остальные строки (1 и 3), которые правильные и под действия триггера не подпадают. Скажите пожалуйста, как это исправить и написать триггер, который в одной вставке будет пускать все правильные строки и не пускать неправильные. То есть, чтобы 1 и 3 строка, так как они правильные, были вставлены в таблицу, а 2 строка не была вставлена, так как она неправильная.

Comment: *чтобы 1 и 3 строка, так как они правильные, были вставлены в таблицу, а 2 строка не была вставлена, так как она неправильная.* Запрос или выполняется успешно, или не выполняется по ошибке. Но никак не частично выполняется. Вставляйте данные тремя отдельными запросами. *Нельзя записывать в таблицу результат, в котором x > 120. Поэтому был написан триггер, который отменяет вставку строки, у которой x > 120.* Нафига? Достаточно было CHECK CONSTRAINT.

Comment: Мне нужно это сделать так, чтобы транзакция не откатывалась после срабатывания триггера

Comment: Тогда нужен INSTEAD OF INSERT триггер, который выбросит косые записи и вставит только валидные.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, написать примерный код, который показывает такой триггер, чтоб я понимал суть. Спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1039157/229437

Comment: @РэмКудусов Вам по моему лучше [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/879249/217579). _Нельзя записывать в таблицу результат, в котором x > 120_. Отлично, а зачем вы тогда пытаетесь его записать, вот тут `values ('Marat', 150, 85)`? Ну я конечно могу и с триггером, и даже без `intead of`, предложить рабочее решение, но оно изначально будет не самое лучшее (скорее самое худшее).

Answer (score 2):

Проверка на допустимые значения в триггере или ограничении служит для защиты целостности данных от возможных програмных ошибок (*защита от дурака*). Если такая ошибка возникла,  то её надо устранить, а не пытаться "смягчить" ограничение.

---

Такое решение будет правильным:

```sql
create table shots (name varchar2 (8), x int, y int, 
    constraint chk_shots_x check (x<=120));

insert into shots (name, x, y)
    with source (name, x, y) as ( 
        select 'Bill',   12, 61 from dual union all   
        select 'Marat', 150, 85 from dual union all
        select 'Ivan',   18, 13 from dual)
    select * from source where x<=120; 

2 rows inserted.
```